# Lindblad evolution as continuum limit of a discrete process coupling system and environment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, open-quantum-systems

I have trouble understanding the derivation of the **Lindblad evolution** in terms of the time evolution under a Hamiltonian $H$ in a system-environment Hilbert space $H_S\otimes H_E$, where we trace out the environment after some time $\Delta t$.
In particular, I'd like to understand the Lindbladian $\mathcal L$ as the **continuum limit of some discrete-time process**, involving time evolution under $H$, erasing the environment and preparing it in a state $\omega$, and possibly other things that are necessary.

My first naive approach is to consider process of alternating the discrete-time channels (1) unitary time evolution with $e^{i\Delta t H}$, and (2) reinitialization of the environment $(\mathbb 1_S\otimes \omega)\circ Tr_E$.
To second order in $\Delta t$, this yields
$$\rho+\Delta t\mathcal L(\rho)+\Delta t^2\ldots:= Tr_E(e^{i\Delta tH}(\rho\otimes \omega) e^{-i\Delta tH}) = \rho+i\Delta tTr_E(H(\rho\otimes\omega)-(\rho\otimes\omega)H) + \Delta t^2 Tr_E(H(\rho\otimes \omega) H - \frac12 H^2 (\rho\otimes \omega) - \frac12 (\rho\otimes \omega) H^2) = \rho+\Delta ti[\widetilde H,\rho]+\Delta t^2\sum_i (L_i\rho L_i^\dagger - \frac12 \{L_i L_i^\dagger,\rho\}),$$
for suitably chosen $\widetilde H$ and $L_i$.
In the continuum limit $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$, $\mathcal L$ is given by the first-order term,
$$\mathcal L(\rho) = i[\widetilde H,\rho]$$
If the $\Delta t^2$ above was a $\Delta t$, then everything would be perfect and we would end up with an operator of Lindblad form, but it's not. Of course, physically, taking the limit this way does not make sense because it takes some constant time for the environment to reset itself to $\omega$ itself via thermalization, but we're pretending that this time scales with $\Delta t$. So it's not surprising that this doesn't work. I'm wondering, is there a way to define a discrete circuit consisting of interactions with the environment and relaxation of the environment, such that in the continuum limit we recover the Lindblad evolution? Or in which sense can one even "derive" the Lindblad evolution instead of merely postulating it? What are the precise assumptions that need to be made?

All derivations in the literature that I've found do the calculation that I've shown above, and then become very cryptic arguing that the second-order term somehow behaves like a first-order term.

Comment: AFAIK a fully rigorous derivation of the Lindblad equation can, if at all, only be done in some very simple special cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: if you reset the state of system and environment to a product state after each infinitesimal time step, you obtain a unitary time evolution. Instead, the derivation (due to [Lidar et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0301010401003305), see also [Majenz et al.](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.88.012103)) goes as follows.

- System and environment start in a product state at time $t=0$. They evolve together for a finite time $\tau$. Without any approximation, one can derive that $\rho(\tau) - \rho(0) = \tau\, \mathcal L_\tau[ \rho(0) ]$ for *any* $\tau$. Here, $\rho$ is the reduced state of the system and $\mathcal L_\tau$ a superoperator in Lindblad form.
- We now fix a $\tau$ such that it is much larger than the bath's relaxation time-scale and much smaller than the characteristic system time scale. The first approximation that we make is to reset the state to a product state at the (discrete!) time points $t_n = n\tau$. Therefore, $\rho(n\tau + \tau) - \rho(n\tau) = \tau\, \mathcal L_\tau[ \rho(n\tau) ]$.
- The second approximation is to consider the coarse-grained state $\tilde\rho(t) = \frac 1 \tau \int_t^{t+\tau} \rho(t') dt'$. It does not change much on the time-scale $\tau$ and therefore approximately satisfies $\partial_t \tilde\rho(t) = \mathcal L_\tau[ \tilde\rho(t) ]$ for all times.

So this is explicitly not a continuum limit of discrete coupling / reset processes, but a coarse-graining.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the kind of answer I was hoping to get! What do you mean by the characteristic system time scale? Similarly, what is the reason why you say "It does not change much on the time-scale $\tau$", and what are the conditions on $H$ under which this holds in a limiting case? Maybe something like $\tau |Tr_E(H(\mathbb1\otimes\omega))|<<1$, i.e., the time scale for the effective unitary evolution of $H$ is much smaller than $\tau$?

Comment: @AndiBauer Yes, the timescale of the free (unitary) system evolution should be much larger than $\tau$. The fastest timescale of the system evolution is something like $\tau_s \sim [E_{max}(H_s) - E_{min}(H_s)]^{-1}$, so $\tau_s \gg \tau$. Here, $E_{max}$ and $E_{min}$ are the max. and min. eigenenergies. (Disclaimer: like Norbert Schuch has also said in the comments, I don't believe I have seen all this made fully rigorous.)